# How to prevent scale trumb within flex scrollbar

Tags: apache-flex, scrollbar, scale, skinning

HI, all
I'm looking simply approach to prevent scale thumb within flex scrollbar'
According to our wireframes we should display scrollbar without up-down arrows and cycle (without scale) as a thumb;

Comment: are you saying that you want the thumb to be the same size always?

Comment: @asawilliams Yes I want to know the solution to the problem in your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to skin the scrollbar component.

http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/05/designer_scroll.html
http://www.axelscript.com/2008/02/20/custom-scroll-bar-using-css/
http://www.pixelbox.net/2008/06/02/skinning-scrollbars-in-flex-3/

In my experience though, skinning the scrollbar is painful and frustrating. They have internal hacks regarding the orientation (VScrollBar vs. HSCrollBar) and the sizes of the bar. But you can officially change everything.

Comment: then please clarify what you're looking for. I don't understand.